# Show that $T_{x}$ is not bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $x\in [0,1]$ and $T_{x}\colon \left( C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{1}\right)\to \left(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|\right),\ x\mapsto f(x)$. It is trivial to show that $T_{x}$ is linear operator. We want to show that $T_{x}$ is not bounded. I try, for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, to find $f_{n}\in C[0,1]$ such that, $$\frac{|f_{n}(x)|}{\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}(t)|dt}\to \infty\ ,$$ for $n\to \infty$, but i couldn't find something.
How can we show that $T_{x}$ is not bounded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0 <x<1$ draw a triangle with base $(x-\frac  1 {n^{2}},x+\frac  1 {n^{2}}))$ and height $n$. Let $f_n$ be the cnts function whose graph has two sides of this triangle and which vanishes outside the base of this triangle. Then $\int |f_n| \to 0$ and $f_n(x) \to \infty$. I will leave the cases $x=0$ and $x=1$ to you.

Explicit defintion of $f_n$: $f_n(y)=n^{3}[\frac 1 {n^2}- |y-x|]$ for $|y-x| \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}}$ and $0$ for all other $y$.

Comment: You' re right. Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

$f(y) = 1$ for $y-x<\frac1n,$ and $0$ otherwise. (yes, it is not continuous, but you can easily make it so).